# Can I assume that most Vulkan functions use a lock when calling them?

Tags: vulkan

I mean either a mutex or a spinlock, given that most are not described in the spec as needing to be "externally synchronised", then you can them from multiple threads, therefore they must lock an atomic variable or use a mutex, right? I wish we had a little more control. For example in my code when I create an image I need to lock the function in the image manager, and then when creating the image that's another lock, and when creating the image view that's another lock.

I guess that's the case also for vkdestroyimage and image view.

Comment: "*For example in my code when I create an image I need to lock the function in the image manager, and then when creating the image that's another lock, and when creating the image view that's another lock.*" Nobody's forcing you to program your system that way. Also, the creation of `VkImage` objects should never be done on a performance-critical codepath.

Comment: @NicolBolas How do you add an image to a container without a lock? Otherwise you're limited to creation of images from only one thread. And if you use the trick deferring the creation of the image so that it's only ever done from one thread you still have to add to a container so the main thread knows what to create.

Comment: "*How do you add an image to a container without a lock?*" With lock-free programming techniques.

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve? This sounds like a lot of hypothetical problems without any actual data showing it actually is a problem ...

Comment: Locks on modern processors are generally very fast unless the lock is contended, so unless you have a lot of threads creating tens of thousands of images concurrently I really doubt there is a real problem here. Data upload to the image will dwarf the cost of any locking overhead in the driver (if there is any).

Answer (score 1):

No, those functions without "externally synchronised" are basically a read access. You need to protect write from writes (i.e. two externally synchronised parameters), and reads from write (i.e. non-externally synchronised from externally synchronised).

On modern computers, read-read is not hazard, therefore there's usually no need to synchronize it. In rare cases there has to writes in the implementation, then it **is** internally synchronized. (This is oftentimes the case of enabled validation layers, since they need to store what you did in the API)

In the case of `vkDestroyImage` **all** uses of the image must cease. That includes any other threads using it too.

Comment: "No, those functions without "externally synchronised" are basically a read access." vkCreateImage is only read access? How? It creates a handle?

Comment: @Zebrafish `vkCreateImage` is the only owner of the handle until it returns it to you. You literally cannot call something with that instance on another thread, because you don't have the handle yet. Until it returns it to you, it is just implementation detail (and so the command can write into it how much it wants). It doesn't write to any **shared objects** (or it is internally synchronized, like say e.g. `malloc()`s).

Comment: It can't just read a value and return it as a handle to you without writing something, either a pointer or a counter or something. So it needs to block other threads while it's dispensing the handle to the other thread.

Comment: @Zebrafish I am not sure what you mean. As far as External Synchronization is concerned, it does not write shared objects. There are not even any before Instance creation.

Comment: I mean that you can call vkCreateImage from two different threads safely. It's like calling malloc from two different threads, it has to use some sort of lock/synchronisation, right? It can't be a read only operation, it's dispensing a handle with a unique value. So every time you call vkCreateImage, or anything that gives you a new handle, and maybe the destroy functions to it's using either a mutex or a spin lock or something. Right?

Comment: @Zebrafish Yea, you can call `vkCreateImage` from  threads, as long as you are not also calling `vkDestroyDevice` (which has the `device` parameter as externally synchronized). Creation has no reason to lock, other than perhaps it is perusing `malloc`, which is already made thread-safe by the language\OS. Destroy functions are marked as Externally Synchronized; i.e. you have to cease use of the thing you are about to destroy.